# Two level cache and lifetime issue (for specialist!!!)

Tags: cache, memcached

I've an issue  with the two level cache, here the situation:
- fast cache : memcache
- slow : database but with store_data false (i only keep tags)

When i try to save in cache custom data with lifetime using:

```
Mage::app()->getCache()->save(serialize($value),$cacheId,array("custom_tag"), 180);
```

The value is saved in memcached but the lifetime is not set (so i have an infinity expiration time, the only solution is to flush the cache.

I search into Magento code and i think the issue is in the **TwoLevels.php** file (in lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/TwoLevels.php), indeed, when the value is save we have:

```
$fastLifetime = $this->_getFastLifetime($lifetime, $priority);
$boolFast = $this->_fastBackend->save($preparedData, $id, array(), $fastLifetime);
$boolSlow = $this->_slowBackend->save($preparedData, $id, $tags, $lifetime);
```

We can see that the lifetime for the FastBackend (memcache in my case) is modified by the **_getFastLifetime** function and here is this function:

```
private function _getFastLifetime($lifetime, $priority, $maxLifetime = null)
{
    if ($lifetime <= 0) {
        // if no lifetime, we have an infinite lifetime
        // we need to use arbitrary lifetimes
        $fastLifetime = (int) (2592000 / (11 - $priority));
    } else {
        // prevent computed infinite lifetime (0) by ceil
        $fastLifetime = (int) ceil($lifetime / (11 - $priority));
    }

    if ($maxLifetime >= 0 && $fastLifetime > $maxLifetime) {
        return $maxLifetime;
    }

    return $fastLifetime;
}
```

The issue in this function is that even if we don't passed $maxlifeTime argument, so null is used  the condition **$maxLifetime >= 0** is still true so the return value become $maxlifetime ( so null) instead of $lifetime.

Can anyone confirm that this is a bug?